# Can a Shoddy Item be made into a Masterwork item?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, feats

This question concerns the feat *[Craft Shoddy Item](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Craft%20Shoddy%20Item)* and how it interacts with the spell *[Masterwork Transformation](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Masterwork%20Transformation)* - in particular, **can a shoddy item be the target of masterwork transformation?**

---

I believe the majority of any confusion I’ve seen concerning this arises from the description of *Shoddy Items* (available via the AoN link for the feat) which reads:

> ...*Shoddy items are never masterwork or made of special materials*....

My understanding of this clause is that - *at the time of creation and without manipulation* - the item cannot be considered masterwork, regardless of any ability or effect that would cause it to be so. This makes it unsuitable for enchantment, etc.

However, a shoddy item for which there exists a masterwork variant of that item - *for example, a longsword* - does have a masterwork form; it is simply not shoddy at that point.

This means the failure clause of masterwork transformation does not trigger, and the spell will successfully transform the shoddy item into a masterwork item.

> ...*If the target object has no masterwork equivalent, the spell has no effect*.

My main reasoning for this lies in the particular phrasing of the shoddy items masterwork restriction; *”are never masterwork“* does not mean the same as *” can never be masterwork“*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There simply aren’t any more rules we can offer here, and you’ve already laid out the rules we do have.

- It’s not clear if *shoddy* should be treated similarly to *masterwork*, as a modifier on the item that can potentially change—if so, then *masterwork transformation* can apply to the item, and since *shoddy* and *masterwork* are mutually exclusive (per *shoddy*’s description), the result is a *masterwork* item.
- Alternatively, a *shoddy item* could be separate from a regular *item*, and because *shoddy* is mutually exclusive with *masterwork*, the *shoddy item* counts as an item as an “object [that] has no masterwork equivalent, [so] the spell [*masterwork transformation*] has no effect.”

Either is a reasonable reading of the rules; neither is clearly correct. You’ll have to ask your GM, or make a decision for yourself if you are the GM. Allowing *masterwork transformation* means characters could potentially save some money by buying shoddy ites and casting *masterwork transformation* on them; it’s a very small amount of money, though, so that isn’t a big deal. Disallowing it means shoddy items inevitably must be replaced, which may be a negative if the item’s story has been significant and the character wants to keep it for sentimental reasons—which is arguably why *masterwork transformation* exists. Or you could split the difference, and say you can cast *masterwork transformation* on a shoddy item but it requires more material components—exactly enough to counteract the savings of having bought a shoddy item to begin with.